# CEPH cluster deployment

Tags: ceph

> I am trying to deploy a CEPH cluster with 4 nodes.
> admin, node1, node2, client
> I am using Oracle VM VIrtual Box to deploy centos 8 nodes.
>
> I am using CEPH Octopus.
>
> I am using ansible-playbook to deploy the cluster
>
> I followed the steps listed in this blog to deploy my cluster:
> https://computingforgeeks.com/install-and-configure-ceph-storage-cluster-on-centos-linux/?amp#ex1

[mons]
admin monitor_address=192.168.1.75

```
[mdss]
admin

[osds]
node1
node2

[clients]
node3

[mgrs]
admin

[grafana-server]
node2
```

but every time the process gets halted and I am receiving the following error:

```
  TASK [ceph-osd : use ceph-volume lvm batch to create bluestore osds] ***********
Wednesday 21 July 2021  11:29:51 +0530 (0:00:00.085)       0:02:06.609 ***********
fatal: [node2]: FAILED! => changed=true
  cmd:
  - ceph-volume
  - --cluster
  - ceph
  - lvm
  - batch
  - --bluestore
  - --yes
  - --osds-per-device
  - '4'
  - /dev/sdb
  delta: '0:50:01.301186'
  end: '2021-06-07 16:19:53.554904'
  msg: non-zero return code
  rc: 1
  start: '2021-06-07 15:29:52.253718'
  stderr: |-
    --> DEPRECATION NOTICE
    --> You are using the legacy automatic disk sorting behavior
    --> The Pacific release will change the default to --no-auto
    --> passed data devices: 1 physical, 0 LVM
    --> relative data size: 0.25
    Running command: /bin/ceph-authtool --gen-print-key
    Running command: /bin/ceph --cluster ceph --name client.bootstrap-osd --keyring /var/lib/ceph/bootstrap-osd/ceph.keyring -i - osd new 4f1d0cc7-0363-4d06-84e8-c45be914159b
     stderr: 2021-06-07T15:34:53.415+0530 7f018bcde700  0 monclient(hunting): authenticate timed out after 300
     stderr: 2021-06-07T15:39:53.418+0530 7f018bcde700  0 monclient(hunting): authenticate timed out after 300
     stderr: 2021-06-07T15:44:53.420+0530 7f018bcde700  0 monclient(hunting): authenticate timed out after 300
     stderr: 2021-06-07T15:49:53.422+0530 7f018bcde700  0 monclient(hunting): authenticate timed out after 300
     stderr: 2021-06-07T15:54:53.423+0530 7f018bcde700  0 monclient(hunting): authenticate timed out after 300
     stderr: 2021-06-07T15:59:53.425+0530 7f018bcde700  0 monclient(hunting): authenticate timed out after 300
     stderr: 2021-06-07T16:04:53.427+0530 7f018bcde700  0 monclient(hunting): authenticate timed out after 300
     stderr: 2021-06-07T16:09:53.428+0530 7f018bcde700  0 monclient(hunting): authenticate timed out after 300
     stderr: 2021-06-07T16:14:53.430+0530 7f018bcde700  0 monclient(hunting): authenticate timed out after 300
     stderr: 2021-06-07T16:19:53.432+0530 7f018bcde700  0 monclient(hunting): authenticate timed out after 300
     stderr: [errno 110] RADOS timed out (error connecting to the cluster)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/sbin/ceph-volume", line 11, in <module>
        load_entry_point('ceph-volume==1.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'ceph-volume')()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ceph_volume/main.py", line 40, in __init__
        self.main(self.argv)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ceph_volume/decorators.py", line 59, in newfunc
        return f(*a, **kw)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ceph_volume/main.py", line 152, in main
        terminal.dispatch(self.mapper, subcommand_args)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ceph_volume/terminal.py", line 194, in dispatch
        instance.main()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ceph_volume/devices/lvm/main.py", line 42, in main
        terminal.dispatch(self.mapper, self.argv)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ceph_volume/terminal.py", line 194, in dispatch
        instance.main()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ceph_volume/decorators.py", line 16, in is_root
        return func(*a, **kw)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ceph_volume/devices/lvm/batch.py", line 415, in main
        self._execute(plan)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ceph_volume/devices/lvm/batch.py", line 434, in _execute
        c.create(argparse.Namespace(**args))
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ceph_volume/decorators.py", line 16, in is_root
        return func(*a, **kw)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ceph_volume/devices/lvm/create.py", line 26, in create
        prepare_step.safe_prepare(args)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ceph_volume/devices/lvm/prepare.py", line 252, in safe_prepare
        self.prepare()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ceph_volume/decorators.py", line 16, in is_root
        return func(*a, **kw)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ceph_volume/devices/lvm/prepare.py", line 292, in prepare
        self.osd_id = prepare_utils.create_id(osd_fsid, json.dumps(secrets), osd_id=self.args.osd_id)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ceph_volume/util/prepare.py", line 173, in create_id
        raise RuntimeError('Unable to create a new OSD id')
    RuntimeError: Unable to create a new OSD id
  stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: ''
  stdout_lines: <omitted>
fatal: [node1]: FAILED! => changed=true
  cmd:
  - ceph-volume
  - --cluster
  - ceph
  - lvm
  - batch
  - --bluestore
  - --yes
  - --osds-per-device
  - '4'
  - /dev/sdb
  delta: '0:50:02.352739'
  end: '2021-06-07 16:19:54.591371'
  msg: non-zero return code
  rc: 1
  start: '2021-06-07 15:29:52.238632'
  stderr: |-
    --> DEPRECATION NOTICE
    --> You are using the legacy automatic disk sorting behavior
    --> The Pacific release will change the default to --no-auto
    --> passed data devices: 1 physical, 0 LVM
    --> relative data size: 0.25
    Running command: /bin/ceph-authtool --gen-print-key
    Running command: /bin/ceph --cluster ceph --name client.bootstrap-osd --keyring /var/lib/ceph/bootstrap-osd/ceph.keyring -i - osd new 8b324b40-b7d4-4e97-9178-e0f987fd3b67
     stderr: 2021-06-07T15:34:53.504+0530 7fbccc9f2700  0 monclient(hunting): authenticate timed out after 300
     stderr: 2021-06-07T15:39:53.531+0530 7fbccc9f2700  0 monclient(hunting): authenticate timed out after 300
     stderr: 2021-06-07T15:44:53.560+0530 7fbccc9f2700  0 monclient(hunting): authenticate timed out after 300
     stderr: 2021-06-07T15:49:53.775+0530 7fbccc9f2700  0 monclient(hunting): authenticate timed out after 300
     stderr: 2021-06-07T15:54:53.799+0530 7fbccc9f2700  0 monclient(hunting): authenticate timed out after 300
     stderr: 2021-06-07T15:59:53.820+0530 7fbccc9f2700  0 monclient(hunting): authenticate timed out after 300
     stderr: 2021-06-07T16:04:53.846+0530 7fbccc9f2700  0 monclient(hunting): authenticate timed out after 300
     stderr: 2021-06-07T16:09:53.849+0530 7fbccc9f2700  0 monclient(hunting): authenticate timed out after 300
     stderr: 2021-06-07T16:14:54.327+0530 7fbccc9f2700  0 monclient(hunting): authenticate timed out after 300
     stderr: 2021-06-07T16:19:54.476+0530 7fbccc9f2700  0 monclient(hunting): authenticate timed out after 300
     stderr: [errno 110] RADOS timed out (error connecting to the cluster)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/sbin/ceph-volume", line 11, in <module>
        load_entry_point('ceph-volume==1.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'ceph-volume')()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ceph_volume/main.py", line 40, in __init__
        self.main(self.argv)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ceph_volume/decorators.py", line 59, in newfunc
        return f(*a, **kw)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ceph_volume/main.py", line 152, in main
        terminal.dispatch(self.mapper, subcommand_args)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ceph_volume/terminal.py", line 194, in dispatch
        instance.main()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ceph_volume/devices/lvm/main.py", line 42, in main
        terminal.dispatch(self.mapper, self.argv)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ceph_volume/terminal.py", line 194, in dispatch
        instance.main()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ceph_volume/decorators.py", line 16, in is_root
        return func(*a, **kw)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ceph_volume/devices/lvm/batch.py", line 415, in main
        self._execute(plan)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ceph_volume/devices/lvm/batch.py", line 434, in _execute
        c.create(argparse.Namespace(**args))
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ceph_volume/decorators.py", line 16, in is_root
        return func(*a, **kw)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ceph_volume/devices/lvm/create.py", line 26, in create
        prepare_step.safe_prepare(args)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ceph_volume/devices/lvm/prepare.py", line 252, in safe_prepare
        self.prepare()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ceph_volume/decorators.py", line 16, in is_root
        return func(*a, **kw)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ceph_volume/devices/lvm/prepare.py", line 292, in prepare
        self.osd_id = prepare_utils.create_id(osd_fsid, json.dumps(secrets), osd_id=self.args.osd_id)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ceph_volume/util/prepare.py", line 173, in create_id
        raise RuntimeError('Unable to create a new OSD id')
    RuntimeError: Unable to create a new OSD id
  stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: ''
  stdout_lines: <omitted>
```

Please help me with this. I was successful only 2 times out of the 10 times I tried.
I used the same configuration every time.

Comment: I am using ceph octopus.

Comment: Can you add the docs you're following? I'm not familiar with ansible but `error connecting to the cluster` usually means that the node is missing a ceph.conf and/or the appropriate keyrings.

Comment: @eblock: I followed the steps listed on this blog,                                  https://computingforgeeks.com/install-and-configure-ceph-storage-cluster-on-centos-linux/?amp#ex1

Comment: Please edit your question with additional information instead of commenting them so all information is at one single place. Can you verify that the `ceph.conf` and `/var/lib/ceph/bootstrap-osd/ceph.keyring` have been created successfully on the osd node(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Change OSD nodes to 3 nodes and try again because of quorum, or you can activate test mode from this config file:
group_vars/all.yml ---> change ceph_test: false to ceph_test: true